# Ajax function content type

Tags: javascript, ajax

I don't know ajax very well but have the following function:

```
function saveViaAJAX() {  
    var canvasData = $("#wPaint").wPaint("image");
    var postData = "canvasData="+canvasData;

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST",'testSave.php',true);    
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'canvas/upload');

    ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) { 
            document.getElementById("debugFilenameConsole").innerHTML="Saved as<br><a target='_blank' href='"+ajax.responseText+"'>"+ajax.responseText+" </a><br>Reload this page to generate new image or click the filename to open the image file in a new window.";
        }
     }

    ajax.send(postData);  
}
```

This works fine but I have another variable i want to pass to testSave.php

```
<select id="website_string" name="website_string"> 
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="A4">A4</option>
    <option value="A5">A5</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to pass this in the same function but it's ("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") I think.

Comment: You are already using jQuery, so use its AJAX functionality as well. You can make an AJAX POST with [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). There are examples.

Comment: You can anyway send it as GET variable `ajax.open("POST",'testSave.php?website_string=A4',true);`.

Comment: What's `canvas/upload`? The data your sending is probably in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` anyway.

Comment: sending the canvas as an image file to FPDF so it has to be ('Content-Type', 'canvas/upload').
how do I know if A4 or A5 is selected for 'testSave.php?website_string=A4'?

Comment: if ($_GET['website_string] == 'A4') doSomething();

Comment: thanks for the help, get an odd error now in testSave1.php for
        $stringData = $_POST['website_string'];
        echo $stringData;
 Notice: Undefined index: website_string in C:\wamp\www\testSave1.php on line 5

Comment: whoops; should be GET